# Which strings to store in strings.xml?

Tags: android, xml, string

Are there any suggestions on which strings you should store in strings.xml and which strings can be stored as String objects? For example, do I have to put a string into strings.xml, if I use it only to complete a certain action and then it can be destroyed? And what is the main reason in storing strings in xml? Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any string that will be displayed to the user should be in strings.xml.  This is useful in case you ever want to support other languages for your application.  If you do, you just create a new strings.xml file that language with translated values.  You can learn more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).

Answer (score 3):

One reason is multi-language support. 
You should store the strings that you use in Activities - TextView, button's caption and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You should put most constants in strings.xml, your app title, button names, textview contents...mostly things that wont change in your application.

Another reason for storing strings in xml is for localization.  You can store different files for each different `Locale` or language, and Android will grab the correct file for the phone's selected `Locale` or language.

Here is a link to the [String resource Android page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html), it will go more deeply into how the language support is done.

Answer (score 0):

You don't store all the strings in strings.xml, but only strings constants related to user interface, the strings that you want to translate in different languages.

You can have different folder like :

- values
- values-fr
- values-de

in each a strings.xml file with you UI messages translated in many languages.

Regards, 
 Stéphane